# deploy angular 2 app to github pages - failed

Tags: angular, github, npm

I've been trying to deploy my angular 2 app to github pages so I can view the app on the hosted github link but no luck so far.

As soon as I finished my app, I ran these commands:

```
ng build --prod

git remote add origin "My REPO"
git commit -a
git push -u origin master
```

I then tried to running on terminal

```
ng github-pages:deploy
```

and got this error:

```
The specified command github-pages:deploy is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.
```

After researching I ran across this page and followed the instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-github-pages

I installed angular-cli-github-pages via npm on my project directory:

```
npm install --save-dev angular-cli-github-pages
```

it says I have to create the gh-pages so I ran this command below:

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
```

and then committed the files and pushed the changes and returned back to the origin master and ran the deploy command and it gave me the same error:

```
  The specified command github-pages:deploy is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.
```

I've been going back and forth with different methods and it's not working. Can someone please point what I should do to properly deploy this to github pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced the same issue recently. After scouring the angular2 community for hours I was able to find that the angular-cli-github-pages module has been removed in the latest angular-cli release. To deploy your Angular 2 apps to gh-pages , you now need to install a new npm module which is quite similar to the older angular-cli-github-pages module but makes you do a little more work that the previous module.

The npm module is [angular-cli-ghpages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages) . You can find the documentation and steps on the npmjs page for the module.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: **Note:** There is a bug which keeps asking about your email even thought you have set it at user.name. Use the following command to get it working: `ngh --no-silent --email=email@server.com`

Comment: @AnandRockzz, honestly I didn't face this issue. But I kept facing another issue where the cache file would store the repo I hosted on gh-pages and wouldnt let me host a second project. So for that I had to locate the cache file and remove it altogether. I feel that issue arose because I installed the module globally, so if you install it within your repo, you shouldnt face that issue.

Thanks for your finding and its resolution though.

Comment: In my case, it is deployed successfully and loading https linked scripts but not local js bundle scripts and css source files, thus results in blank page. In GitHub issues, a person commented to add the source file links according to relative location. I did that too, still no luck. What I'm thinking is, my angular GitHub page is not running under a server..! So it's unable to load local scripts

Answer (score 1):

I find that the easiest way to deploy to Github Pages is to either use master branch or docs in master branch as the source option in Settings. I go for the docs in master branch option and treat the docs folder as the build directory. It has worked pretty well. I just push to master, Github detects the docs folder and then creates the app/page with its contents.

Comment: I think it's the best approach instead of using a third party library. but still being forced to use the master/main branch which is not equitable for all senarios.

Answer (score 1):

At First Install angular-cli ghpages

```
npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages
```

After installing next step is linking your repository. Run this command

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://<user-name>.github.io/<repo>/"
```

If You See Error Then ommit --prod and Run This Command

```
ng build --base-href "https://<user-name>.github.io/<repo>/"
```

You can now see a dist folder in your angular 2 app directory.

Upload all files of dist folder on github repository.

Then From Settings Enable Github Pages. A link will be provided to you.

That's It.

Demo : https://shawon100.github.io/angularmaterial/

Comment: Your are not using angular-cli-ghpages at all. You only have installed it.

Comment: I think without  installing angular-cli-ghpages you can not run build command.

Comment: The command 'ng build' is from Angular. The command 'ngh' is from angular-cli-ghpages.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your Angular application to Github follow the next steps:

1. Install [*Angular-cli-ghpages*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages) npm package:

   > npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages
2. Execute "ng build" to generate the *dist* folder:

   > ng build --base-href "https://.github.io//"
3. Execute "ngh" (Angular-cli-ghpages) to publish site to your Github repository.

   > sudo ngh --repo https://github.com// --no-silent

The console will show something like this:

```
Cloning https://github.com/<username>/repo into ../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli-ghpages/node_modules/gh-pages/.cache

Cleaning

Fetching origin

Checking out origin/gh-pages

Removing files

Copying files

Adding all

Committing

Pushing

Successfully published!
```

This will push your local *dist* folder to a branch called "*gh-pages*" into your *Github* repository.
Then in your *Github* repository, click on *Settings*, go to *GitHub Pages* section and select "*gh-pages branch*" in the drop-down selector.

**Note:** Next time you make changes and want to deploy your app, execute the step 2 and 3. Take in care that it takes some time (minutes) to refresh the changes in Github.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **angular-cli-ghpages** https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages

I assume you were able to push the code successfully to the repo. Make sure the following things are in place:

1. Angular Cli Version should be 8+.
2. Repo should be public and not private - navigate to settings and change the repo to 
   public.
3. Try the following command: ng deploy --repo=https://github.com// -- 
   base-href=https://.github.io//

Check the network tab to see if the bundles are being loaded successfully, else clear the cache once and try : ctrl + shift + R.